# How to display new data changes on the front end using Polymer 1.0?

Tags: json, database, refresh, polymer, reload

I am a complete noob at google Polymer. I am currently using Polymer 1.0. I am building a dashboard that actively displays the health status of servers. I have a function that grabs URLs from table X in a database, checks if they are responding, and then accordingly updates table X with "success" or "failure" for each of the URLs. I then have the table X rows show up as JSON text at a specific http URL. I used the iron-ajax element to access this URL and bind that JSON text to a polymer element. So when I go to my locally hosted website, I see a bunch of polymer element squares show up reading either success or failure. The problem is that I ping these URLs every 1 minute, but once the page is loaded, the polymer element squares showing the URL status do not change accordingly. So for example, lets say I go to my locally hosted website and it is showing that all of my URLs are responding. However, 2 minutes later, my scheduled function rechecks these URLs and updates table X in the database with a "failure" reading for one of the URLs. The polymer element on my locally hosted website won't refresh itself and display the failure status.

How do I make sure that any updates made to table X show up accordingly on the user interface. Is there a way to do this with Polymer?

Here is the piece of code I am working with:

```
<iron-ajax
            auto="true"
            url="http://localhost:1500"
            last-response="{{statusSquare}}"
            handle-as="json">
    </iron-ajax>
    <div class="body">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{statusSquare}}">
            <div class="square">{{item.appName}}<br><br><br><span>{{item.statusURLTxt}}</span></div>
        </template>
    </div>
```

Comment: To confirm, you want iron-ajax to reload the information every minute after the sever-side script runs to ping the servers? You could use an interval to run the iron-ajax every minute, or look into [server side events](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) to have the server push new information whenever a success/failure status changes.

Comment: @KevinAshcraft I promise I've researched this stuff for the last two days and I am not being lazy. I am brand new to programming so could you please show me example code of using an interval to run iron-ajax every minute? Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: It'd be something like: var ajax = this.$$('iron-ajax'); setInterval(function(){ ajax.generateRequest()}, 1000);

Comment: @KevinAshcraft Got it to work with a few edits! Thanks a lot!